# Required Properties on optional Entity Framework Complex Types

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I want to define `[Required]` attributes on a Complex Type in Entity Framework.  For example, I have a `Customer` entity with an optional `Address`.  The Address entity has a required `PostCode` property.

```
[ComplexType]
public class Address {
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}

public class Customer {
    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public Address Address {get;set;}
}
```

I do NOT want to store my Complex type as a separate entity (I'm not actually using Address, this just an easy illustration of the problem).  I cannot leave Customer.Address null, because this gives the error:

> Null value for non-nullable member. Member: 'Address'.

If I supply an empty Address entity, the validation fails on the PostCode field because of the Required attribute.

Is there any way to achieve this?  I'm using EF5/NET4.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible with a complex type.  You'll need to create an Address entity if you want it to be nullable.

What EF will do with a complex type is map the properties to the same table - which it sounds like you've intended.

Because of that - your schema for your example would look like this:

[image]

With a non-nullable column for Address_PostCode, since it's not valid in the database there's not a way for EF to create the row, without your object having an address, and a postcode.

Comment: Was really hoping to do this without a different entity.  Guess I'll have to do validation a bit differently.  Thanks for confirming my suspicions anyway!

Comment: This is a really bad feature of EF. Using reflection on an Address object, EF can easily work out what columns to create on table creation. It doesn't need to have an instance of Address from the entity to work that out. And on entity creation/updating, if the ComplexType property was null, what's so hard about setting those columns in the database to null? This should be an easy feature addition to the next version of EF IMO.