# C# Entity Framework nested members in one row

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework and I want to store nested members in a database, but all of them in one row (I have many nested members and do not want to have so many tables).

I found out, that using inner classes works exactly like I want, for example:

```
public class ClassA
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }

    public virtual ClassB B {get;set;}
    public virtual ClassC C { get; set; }

    public class ClassB
    {
        public int b { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassC
    {
        public int c { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This works really how I want but there is one problem: the inner classes must not be null. For example:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
a.B = new ClassA.ClassB();
a.B.b = 10;
a.C = null;
```

Throws an exception "Null value for non-nullable member".
Is it possible (e.g. with annotations) to make it nullable?

Thank you very much!

Comment: public int? c { get; set; }

Comment: Take a look at this - http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types. Also keep the classes separate (do not use nested class); include them as property inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the nested members in one row (same row of the main member, ClassA in your case) you have to mark them as ComplexTypes.

```
[ComplexType]
public class ClassB
{
    public int b { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class ClassC
{
    public int c { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, in ClassA table will contain the columns for ClassB and ClassC.
For use this configuration you need that properties ClassA.B and ClassA.C are always not null but you can mark ClassB and ClassC properties (b and c) as nullable.

When I use complex types I use a model similar to this

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        // Create Always complex type instances
        B = new ClassB();
        C = new ClassC();
    }

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }

    public ClassB B { get; set; } // virtual is not required by EF because this property won't be lazy loaded
    public ClassC C { get; set; }

    [ComplexType]
    public class ClassB
    {
        public int? b { get; set; }
    }

    [ComplexType]
    public class ClassC
    {
        public int? c { get; set; }
    }
}
```

About nullable ComplexTypes you can have a look here
[Complex Types of Nullable Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380702/complex-types-of-nullable-values)
[Required Properties on optional Entity Framework Complex Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856202/required-properties-on-optional-entity-framework-complex-types)

Otherwise you can have more (several in your case) tables with 1-1 relationships.
You can search about this configuration on stack overflow. If B and C properties are often null and ClassB and ClassC have several properties this configuration could be also more efficient during write (it depends on DBMS and on block length).

Comment: thanks! this works for me.
I always tried to make the members of "A" nullable, such as "public ClassB? B {get;set;}, which did not work. The solution is to make all members of the "ComplexType" (such as "int? b" and "int? c" ) nullable!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have used the ClassB and ClassC as navigation properties.
you can add a foreign key property.

```
public int? ClassCId { get; set; }
```

In the dbcontext class, you can add this relationship for ClassA using fluent api  instead of data annotations. Fluent api give you more control in creating relationships.

```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    { 
       modelBuilder.Entity<ClassA>()
           .HasOptional(c => c.ClassC)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(c => c.ClassCId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

you can do the same for ClassB.

Comment: did this help you?

Comment: Probably HasOptional/WithRequired fits better but using this configuration you will have 3 tables (and not one row)